# Are $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I have two sets $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$ and need to prove they are homeomorphic.

I believe I can use the function $f(x,y): (x,y) \mapsto \left(\frac 1x, \frac 1y\right)$ for $x \neq 0, y \neq 0 $ and $(x,y) \mapsto (0,0)$ for $x=0,y=0$ here.

I know if I can prove this mapping is open and continuous then I've got a homeomorphism, and continuous is implied by the $x$ and $y$ functions continuous, but I'm having difficulty proving it's an open mapping. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think they are not homeomorphic. First one is simply connected but second one does not.

Comment: Right, the two aren't homeomorphic. Is the one set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < x^2+y^2 < 1\}$ perhaps?

Comment: I've checked the question on my assignment - the sets are as I've written them and it says to show they are homeomorphic. If they aren't, how can I prove they are not? Do I prove one is not connected?

Comment: Proving something is false can simply be done by giving one example of a case where the statement does no longer hold.

Comment: @Isabelle : Not connected. "Simply connected". Are you familiar with this term, and why it must be preserved under a homeomorphism?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I have read about it but we didn't cover it in class, so I know what it is, but not how to show it or why homeomorphisms preserve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573365/prove-x-y-in-mathbb-r2x2-y2-1-is-not-simply-connected#comment1213341_573365

Answer (score 2):

Here are some basic definitions that you should read up elsewhere before working on this problem :

1. A path
2. A path homotopy
3. Simply connected space. In particular, note that any convex set is automatically simply connected (Why?)

Now prove

> Let $F: X\to Y$ be continuous and $f,g : [0,1] \to X$ be two path-homotopic paths. Then, $F\circ f$ is path-homotopic to $F\circ g$

and

> If $F:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $X$ is simply connected, then $Y$ is simply connected

Conclude that the two sets you have in mind cannot be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that these two sets are not homeomorphic. Algebraic-topologically speaking, the fundamental group of the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb {R}^{2} \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ is trivial while the fundamental group of the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$ is not, so that their fundamental groups are not isomorphic implying that the two spaces in question cannot be homeomorphic with each other.