# Prove $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$ is not simply connected

Tags: general-topology

I have literally no idea how to do this. My assignment question asks me to prove that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$ and $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ are homeomorphic to each other, which they can't be because only one is simply connected. So I need either a counterexample or a counter-proof to this, but I don't know how to get one as I'm not supposed to need it. Help!

I understand that one being simply connected and one not proves what I want, I just don't know how to show that that is the case.

To clarify: This is a result of a mistake in the question. We were asked to prove that there is a homeomorphism between $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$. It was only when I was researching ways to do this that I was told that because one is simply connected and one isn't, there can't be a homeomorphism. I don't want to lose out on credit for the question, but we haven't ever covered paths, simply connected, etc. in class.

Comment: Simply connected is a good idea, but if we think about the proof of some results, it may be simpler to consider *retraction* onto the circle (resp. point) as distinguishing characteristics.

Comment: Well, you already have given a proof that those two spaces are not homeomorphic: one is simply connected and the other is not (assuming you can prove those two assertions). What more do you need?

Comment: @Magdiragdag It may depend on how "simply connected" was defined/introduced. In complex analysis this is often done via "the complement in $\overline{\mathbb C}$ is connected" which does not immediately make it a topological invariant.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to prove something is or is not simply connected.

Comment: I understand you haven't yet studied the fundamental group and stuff, uh @Isabelle ? That'd make this exercise almost completely trivial

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to show that it is not simply connected. You really need to have studied the fundamental group or homotopy at the very least. I suggest you just point out to your instructor that there is a mistake in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea. All you need to prove is that if $X$ is a simply connected space and $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $Y$ is also simply connected. If you already have that result, then there's nothing even to prove. Simply point out that only one of the two is simply connected, and you're done.

As a side note, if we add a "point at infinity" to the former set, then the two sets *are* homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following machinery in your class yet?

1. If a space $X$ deformation retracts onto a subspace $Z$, then they have the same fundamental group.
2. The fundamental group of the circle is non-trivial.

If no, I think you may need to provide more background on which tools you are supposed to use since it's not so simple to prove (2) and (2) is equivalent to your question.

If yes, try to write down explicit deformation retractions of these spaces, respectively, to a point, and to a circle (you should be able to picture them in your head; then, write down formulas using $x$, $y$, and a time variable $t$.)

Comment: Funny: I just asked the OP about her/his knowledge of the fundamental group...

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^{2} + y^{2} > 1 \}$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}^{2} - \mathbf{0}$. Clearly, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2} - \mathbf{0}$ are not homeomorphic, because to get $\mathbb{R}^{2} - \mathbf{0}$ we need to *cut out* a point from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, contrary to the definition of *continuous deformation*. This implies that the sets in question cannot be homeomorphic.

Up to this point, I did not assume any knowledge of algebraic topology. To prove that $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^{2} + y^{2} > 1 \}$ is not simply connected, however, we do need some algebraic topology background, because the very term *simply connectedness* is borrowed from algebraic topology, and not from general topology.